# Relative paths for imports

Tags: java, android, white-labelling

I am wondering if there is a way in java to do an import with a relative package path. Something like this:

```
import *.fragments.MyFragment;
```

I would use this in cases that I had a whitelabel app in which I wanted to have the main app have one definition of "MyFragment," but a product flavor needed to define it differently.

Comment: How would this help?

Comment: Because otherwise, the app is oblivious to the product-flavors changes. If I hard-code the import path into the main code of the app, it will just keep using that package's version of the class rather than the product flavor's

Comment: Sure, but how would `*.fragments.MyFragment` disambiguate anything?

Comment: `import` is a convenience for developers. At runtime, classes are always fully qualified.

Comment: Yea, I realize that, but it's kind of beside the point. The point is that I want to use a package path relative to a particular product flavor.

Comment: Since what you want to do is not allowed in Java, you will need to find a different solution to your actual problem.

Comment: How different will the definitions of `MyFragment` be? If there is any code in common, you can use inheritance to share these similarities.

Comment: Yes, but that inheritance will not matter if the package is hard-coded to the base fragment.

Comment: The base fragment isn't the issue. The only issue should be in the code where you create the fragment since you need to know the concrete type. Every where else will use a reference with the base's type. The creation issues can be addressed with a dependency injection library such as Dagger.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Classes are fully qualified things. Even if you could import eg. all classes named Object from all packages, the runtime has to know which one you want to use in any given statement. There is absolutely no way for the runtime to know which class you want without a fully qualified name (that is exactly what the import statements are for). And, if two classes share the same *canonical* name then they are the same class.

To be complete, in vanilla java you can actually load two classes with the same name into the same runtime. You must use a different class loader pointed at different `jars`, though. You can also cleverly craft classpaths such that you shadow other classes within the same classloader (you'll get the class that comes first on the classpath). But the android build system will not let you `dex` multiple classes with the same canonical name. You'll get a `DexException` since everything used to get squeezed into the same `classes.dex` file. I don't know if this restriction has loosed up in multidex world.

To do what you want, you can simply utilize flavor-specific source sets. So you have `src/flavor1/java` contain one definition of the class and then `src/flavor2/java` contain another definition of the same class. If you do this the class cannot be defined in the main source set and must be defined in each and every flavor's source set independently.

Note that flavors generally define types of products and `flavor != variant`. So you'd want a `normal` and a `whitelabel` flavor. In the normal flavor you build with the normal fragment. In whitelabel flavor you build with a different fragement. That's only two different classes.

Beyond that you get into plain old dependency injection and interfaces, which you may choose in order to untie your build philosophy from flavors and gradle's convenient notion of source sets, anyway.

Comment: But that's just the problem. I don't want to change it for every single product flavor, only particular ones as needed.

Comment: @KairisCharm With some changes to build.gradle, you can add a source set which is shared among several flavors. This means that you can have two versions of your fragment which are each in their own source set. Then each flavor can declare which source set it uses.

Comment: @KairisCharm I suspect you're not using flavors correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to @dcow's answer -
You can combine flavours in dimensions. So if you wanna have 4 flavours for example and only two variants of view for them - add two more flavours, set them to one dimension, and your initial flavours to another. And after that build any combination you need.

```
android {
    ...
    flavorDimensions "appversion", "appserver"

    productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationId = "com.myapp.free"
            dimension  "appversion"
        }
        paid {
            applicationId = "com.myapp.paid"
            dimension  "appversion"
        }
        server1{
            dimension  "appserver"
        }
        server2{
            dimension  "appserver"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just about to add this but didn't remember if you get a separate source set for each dimension. I don't think you do so I wasn't sure how this helps cleanup the situation. As pointed out in a comment, you can just manually add a new source set to the flavors you want such that multiple flavors share the same source set eliminating the need to copy-paste the same classes around into multiple flavor-specific sets.